# Is it possible to allow the player to customize their 2D character while not having to remake the animations for each accessory?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to put a character customization menu into my 2D game on Unity, but I'm just wondering when someone finishes customizing their character, can I just make 1 animation and be able for the character to play it no matter what it looks like? It's a little hard to explain so I'll make a simple drawing. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTJoq.png)

I don't really know if it is possible, so it's okay if it's not. I just want to know.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Animation Rigging`

You can learn from official [Unity Tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/rigging-a-sprite-with-the-2d-animation-package#)

Basically you can import the 2D animation package and rigging your 2d Character Sprite.

You can just replace the 2d Skins for customization, then they use the same rigging and animation at the end.